# what is the solution to make sense npm fails to install error

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-scripts

I need to do photo tagging work, I am trying to install make-sense for this, but I am doing the steps mentioned in the installation section, but npm gives an error, I could not find the reason, the solutions I found do not work.

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deeps
```

and when I download and run it, the application works corrupted.

npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: make-sense@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@4.17.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter
npm ERR!   peer @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@"^4.10.0" from @tensorflow-models/coco-ssd@2.2.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd
npm ERR!     @tensorflow-models/coco-ssd@"^2.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @tensorflow-models/posenet@"^2.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@3.21.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter
npm ERR!   peer @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@"^3.0.0-rc.1" from @tensorflow-models/posenet@2.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@tensorflow-models/posenet
npm ERR!     @tensorflow-models/posenet@"^2.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-02-21T11_56_25_808Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-02-21T11_56_25_808Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Looks like a dependency version issue. Check if the node version you are using is compatible with the packages that is being used. If this is an already working project just try `npm ci` instead of `npm install`. This will download packages as per `package-lock.json` instead of `package.json`